# Add custom stylesheet with my custom block

Tags: custom-block

*In my custom block I want to add custom stylesheet to display the block as like i want. How it can be possible.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add the css file:

1. Add next line inside your module's layout file or inside your theme
   `local.xml` layout file (example path for the rwd theme: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml`):

   ```
   <default>
       <reference name="head">
           <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action>
       </reference>
   </default>
   ```
2. Create file inside the skin folder of your theme:

   ```
   skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/css/custom.css
   ```
3. Then you should add an unique identifier for your block (block's
   template). For that purpose use the `id` or `class` attributes.
   Detect the template file (`.phtml`) and add something like this:

   ```
   <div id="my-own-block-unique-identifier">
       <!-- other content here -->
   </div>
   ```
4. Next, write your css rules in the created css file using the unique
   identifier like this:

   ```
   #my-own-block-unique-identifier { color:red; }
   ```

Comment: Thanks ..
Its works.

Comment: @NasrinNabim If it works, please, mark the answer as solution